# JQuery working with title and src attributes

Tags: jquery, function, attributes, each

I am after a script that will onclick of a checkbox will get the src attribute of the input and then go through all the other checkboxes and radio buttons `.each` and remove the checked attribute of any inputs thats title attribute is is `'RQlevel' + this.src`. Hope that is clear enough.

Here is my attempt, however it is not correct.

```
function levels() {
   if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)').each(function()) {
        if($(':input').attr('title', 'RQlevel' + this.src) {
        $(':input').removeAttr('checked');
        });
   });    
}
```

Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/V8FeW/

Comment: This is a bit unclear, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your references to `this` confused. If I understand your question correctly, this should do what you are wanting:

```
function levels() {
  var $this = $(this); // Cache a reference to the element that was clicked
  if ($this.is(':not(:checked)') { // Determine if the clicked element is checked
    $(':input').each(function() { // Loop through every input element
      // Here, 'this' is the current element in the loop and
      // '$this' is the originally clicked element.
      if (this.title === ('RQLevel' + $this.attr('src'))) {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Update:**

I should have realized this earlier, but your main problem is using the `src` attribute as the basis of your comparison. The `src` attribute gets parsed so that when you query it the value will be the absolute URL. That is, instead of the value "2" you would have the value "http://example.com/2". So, you want to use a [data attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes). See my [update](http://jsfiddle.net/V8FeW/14/) of your jsfiddle for a working example.

Also, instead of using the `onclick` attribute to register the event handler, I bound the handler with jQuery's [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method. Here is the updated JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    $(':input').bind('click', function() {
        var src = $(this).data('src');

        if (!this.checked) {
            $('input:checked').each(function(){
                if (this.title === ('RQlevel' + src)) {
                    this.checked = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this: var $this = $(this);

Comment: This looks good but it does not appear to be working. Ive have done a few diagnostics and cannot figure it out. Here is the link to where the code is implemented. If you check the two checkboxes and then uncheck the first of the two checkboxes the second of the 2 should uncheck as well. VISIT :: http://www.divethegap.com/update/diving-trips/adventure-training and click on BEGINNERS to load the form

Comment: Please create an example at jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @Robin, I have updated my answer to address the problem shown in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function levels() {
    if (!this.checked) {
        var src = this.src;
        $('input:checkbox, input:radio').each(function(){
            if (this.title === 'RQlevel' + src) {
                this.checked = false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note that this should be called like this:

```
$('#yourCheckbox').click(levels);
```

Note also that this is checking to see if the title of the element is `RQlevel` followed by the `src` value of the original clicked element. If this is not what you want, replace `src` in the `each` call with `this.src` to check for the `src` value of the current element.

Comment: No you are quite correct with what I am after however when i tested it I found that I could not uncheck the box that would have unchecked another box as well. It simply would not let me uncheck it.