# JQuery using one checkbox to uncheck another programatically

Tags: jquery, input, jsfiddle

I'm after a script where one checkbox will uncheck another. It is a bit complicated though as all the data is loaded programatically. So if a checkbox is unchecked the procedure is to take its src value, then go through the other inputs and find inputs that have a title of 'RQlevel' + the src value of the clicked elements and set it to unchecked.

Here is the current code.

```
function levels() {
  var test = $(this).attr('src'); 
  if ($(this).is(':not(:checked)')) { 
    $(':input').each(function() { 
      if ($(this).attr('title') === ('RQLevel' + test)) {
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

There is a working example here that will illustrate the issue `http://jsfiddle.net/V8FeW/7/`
If both boxes are checked and the first box is then unchecked it should take the second box with it.

Marvellous

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816991/jquery-working-with-title-and-src-attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function levels() {
  var test = $(this).attr('src'); 
  if (!this.checked)
     $('input:checkbox[title=RQlevel' + test + ']').removeAttr('checked');
}

$(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').bind('change', levels);
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/V8FeW/12/

Comment: One more thing. How to add the attribute disabled as well. $('input:checkbox[title=RQlevel' + test + ']').Attr('disabled','disabled');  does not work

Answer (score 1):

`$('input [title="RQlevel"]').attr('checked', $(this).attr('checked'));`

Comment: Thanks but that won't do it as we do not know the id of the other checkbox as they are generated programatically and there may be multiple checkboxes with that title RQlevel that would also have to be unchecked, again not known until the page is generated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a nice, short and elegant solution: http://briancray.com/2009/08/06/check-all-jquery-javascript/

Comment: Thanks but that won't do it either as we are looking for all checkboxes with the same title. We don't know how many their will be and cannot place them in the same fieldset as they are generated programatically based on the clients entries into a form.